# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

This is with reference to this question

[Singular or plural usage for 'face' in the sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102410/singular-or-plural-usage-for-face-in-the-sentence)

There are some formatting suggestions I would like to make to this question. But I am not able to suggest it. Why? I'm able to suggest edits with other questions, even with those whose rep points is above the OP of the post.

This is strange. I've came across such a phenomenon in SE before. May I know why can't I suggest an edit to this question?

Edit:

I've just noticed that the question has recently been edited. Part of my intended suggestions were made. Surprisingly, I was able to suggest the edit to add the remaining suggestions now. How odd? Was there something temporarily wrong with the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. There was already a pending edit, and you couldn't suggest any other edits until that [edit suggestion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/10057)'s fate was decided. You could hover over the grayed out 'edit' button to see the reason you can't suggest edits.